# Why Ajax is always Updating Same Session Cart instead adding new element into it php mysql

Tags: php, ajax, session, cart

I am looking for help, i am working on a shopping cart section, i have product section i am adding items to the cart using ajax request, i am able to add item to the section, it starts updating the cart instead of adding or appending new element to the cart it updates it with new value! the old is removed here is the code

```
    function getproid(id)
    {
        alert(id);
        var p_qty = $('#p_qty'+id).val();

        var product_size = $('#product_size'+id).val();

        var product_price = Number($('#product_price'+id).text());

        var product_id = $('#product_id'+id).val();


        alert(p_qty);

        $.ajaxSetup({
                  headers: {
                      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('input[name="_token"]').val()
                  }
              });
        $.ajax({

                  url: "{{ route('addtocart') }}",
                  method: 'post',
                  data: {

                        product_id:product_id,
                        p_qty:p_qty,
                        product_size:product_size,
                        product_price:product_price
                  },

                  success: function(result){
                  var output = 'Product has been added to cart. <a href="{{route('cart')}}">View cart</a>';

                    jQuery('#view_response').html(output);



                 }


        });
    }
```

here is the code for controller

```
$cart = Session::get('cart');  

           $product_id = $request->product_id;



           if( $request->p_qty !== null)
           {
               $product_quantity = $request->p_qty;
           }
           else
           {
             $product_quantity = 1;
           }

           $product_size = $request->product_size;

           $product_price = $request->product_price;

           $product_total = $product_price *  $product_quantity;

           $cart = [
                    $product_id => [
                        "product_quantity" => $product_quantity,
                        "product_size" => $product_size,
                        "product_price" => $product_price,
                        "product_total" => $product_total

                    ]
            ];

           $cart = Session::put('cart', $cart); 



           return response()->json(['success'=> "Item added to the Cart view cart "]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not overwriting data? See what the value $cart is immediately after $cart = Session::get('cart'); and then again what the value of $cart is after you modify it. My guess is you need to change this:

```
       $cart = [
                $product_id => [
                    "product_quantity" => $product_quantity,
                    "product_size" => $product_size,
                    "product_price" => $product_price,
                    "product_total" => $product_total

                ]
        ];
```

To this:

```
       $cart[] = [
                $product_id => [
                    "product_quantity" => $product_quantity,
                    "product_size" => $product_size,
                    "product_price" => $product_price,
                    "product_total" => $product_total

                ]
        ];
```

or this:

```
       $cart[product_id] = [
                    "product_quantity" => $product_quantity,
                    "product_size" => $product_size,
                    "product_price" => $product_price,
                    "product_total" => $product_total

                ];
```

Or something like that, or perhaps use array_merge(). Either will append to the $cart array, you are just replacing the $cart array. Some basic troubleshooting would've guided you to this answer. That is a best guess without know the structure of $cart.

Also, this looks bad, if a client can send `$request->product_price` then I can set the price to whatever I want, perhaps even -20.00 and you'd owe me money along with the products I ordered. What's your site? Maybe I'll order some stuff and get some money :-)